# ReactiveMongoTemplate findOne for non-existing element does not get called

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, mongotemplate

I'm trying to obtain one document from collection. Document might not exist, and in case of `null` I wan to return default value.

My query and transformation:

```
    return template.findOne(Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("id")), DeviceSettings::class.java)
            .map {
                when (it) {
                    null -> {
                        defaultSettings(clock)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        listOf(
                                Instant.now(clock).toString(),
                                it.nextMeasurement.toString(),
                                it.shouldUpdateFirmware.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
}
```

Unfortunately above map transformation does not get called.

When I simplify call to simple callable it gets called:

```
    return Mono.fromCallable({
        defaultSettings(clock)
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reactor does not use nulls in streams and `fineOne` should return empty mono when there is no result. In your case you should use 
`switchIfEmpty` operator

`template.findOne(...)
  .map { listOf(...) }
  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(defaultSettings(clock))`

Comment: You could use defaultIfEmpty to directly return the value